# Calling a c# function (.cs file) from a javascript file(.js file)

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a javascript file and I have a method "Test" in that method I like to call a c# function.

The c# function is not in the same file as in the javascript file.

It's in a .cs file. So how can I manage that the javascript functions is able to call the c# function ?

I already searched on the internet but most solutions are based on a aspx and apx.cs file...

I tried something like this:

viewer.js

```
function Test() {
alert("Hello world-2");
window.external.MethodToCallFromScript();
}
```

ScriptManager.cs

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    public class ScriptManager
    {
        public void MethodToCallFromScript()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
```

But it did not work...

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to have two seperate files like I now have:

a .cs file where my function is (at this moment just a messagebox showing "hello world" but later it's more than only that-> HTTPWebrequest)

and a .js file where I can call my c# function...

Answer (score 1):

In order to have this working, you must set the `ObjectForScripting`-property of the `WebBrwoser`-control.

Here is an example

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    private Button button1 = new Button();

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        button1.Text = "call script code from client code";
        button1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
        Controls.Add(button1);
        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
        webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
        // Uncomment the following line when you are finished debugging. 
        //webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        webBrowser1.DocumentText =
            "<html><head><script>" +
            "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
            "</script></head><body><button " +
            "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
            "call client code from script code</button>" +
            "</body></html>";
    }

    public void Test(String message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test",
            new String[] { "called from client code" });
    }

}
```

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) is the link.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I actually I dont want the HTML code inside my c# code it's need to be two seperate files...

Comment: The significant line in the example is this one: `webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;`; define yourself a class, create an object and pass it to `ObjectForScripting`. Also, see the link I provided for clarification